# Parcel: unable to marshal value org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am very beginner in Android and Parcelable interface . I just want to send

```
private XMPPTCPConnection xmpptcpConnection;
```

this above XMPPTCPConnection  object from one Activity to another Activity.But I am error getting error as:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection@342f1d60
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1337)
                                                                               at com.example.rahul.samplesmack.Def.writeToParcel(Def.java:31)
```

Below is my java code:

```
public class Def implements Parcelable {

private XMPPTCPConnection xmpptcpConnection;

public void setXmpptcpConnection(XMPPTCPConnection xmpptcpConnection)
{
    this.xmpptcpConnection = xmpptcpConnection;
}
public XMPPTCPConnection getXmpptcpConnection()
{
    return xmpptcpConnection;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(xmpptcpConnection); //I am getting Error here!!!!!
}

public Def(){}
protected Def(Parcel in) {
    xmpptcpConnection = (XMPPTCPConnection) in.readValue(XMPPTCPConnection.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Creator<Def> CREATOR = new Creator<Def>() {
    @Override
    public Def createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Def(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Def[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Def[size];
    }
};
```

}

Comment: `XMPPTCPConnection` is not parcelable and you might want to rethink your design

Comment: Wow !! Thanks for pointing out this